# Application Updating Error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, google-places-api

I Upload A New Version Android App in Google Play store , But Not successfully , I See Error , That Error is Bellow , Please Help Me ?

Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

[ SHA1: 27:7C:DC:76:0B:18:AE:F8:30:3A:48:CA:08:9C:6B:23:44:E6:E4:D2 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 1B:93:3C:5E:55:F5:41:15:8D:64:CC:18:48:0C:A8:4D:7B:47:1B:FD ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the same keystore to sign your APK that you used to sign in the first time

Comment: lost that key store ,

Comment: You can't update any more if you lost the keystore, sorry.

Comment: hey now i recovery old key store then sign then upload app in playstore , now same massage

Comment: Try clear the project, maybe you have a old version of APK